# Dynamically changing href value on an <a> when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, parameters

This is the HTML page, I am working on:

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="script-approval-form" action="" method="post">
        <h3 class="title-submitted">Script Approval</h3>
        <h5> Below you will find the script that needs to be approved before being used: </h5>
        <fieldset>
            <textarea id = "textarea-script-approval" class="textarea-approval"
                      type="textarea" tabindex="1" required autofocus></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input class="email-box" placeholder="Your Email Address (if clarification is needed)"
                   type="email" pattern=".+@COMPANY.com"
                   oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('E-mail MUST end with @COMPANY.com')"
                   value="{{ user_info.email }}" tabindex="2" required>
            <button id = "what" class="submit-btn" type="submit"><a id = "submit-lnk" class="submit-link"
                                                        href = "#"
                                                        >
                                                        Submit for Approval</a>
            </button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
```

It's a form with a pre-filled text-area and a submit button. The text-area is automatically filled in with this JS script:

```
const url = window.location;
const urlObject = new URL(url);
const script = urlObject.searchParams.get('authorize')
var decodedScript = window.atob(script);
document.getElementById("textarea-script-approval").value = decodedScript;
```

It gets the encoded base64 URL parameter (EXAMPLE: url.com/script_approval?authorize=DScdsaCs) and puts it as normal text in the page textarea. However, if the user clicks the submit button/link, he will be sent to another page. I need to pass the script in text form to the next page as well, so for this reason I have to:

- Get current textarea value
- Encode it in base64
- Change href link to `/script-sent?script=${encoded_string}`
- The next page will be opened with the same URL parameter
- I will then use my old JS script to decode and get the string into my other pages textareas/input places

What I tried:

```
<script>
       document.getElementById("submit-lnk").onclick = function() {
           var script=document.getElementById("textarea-script-approval").value;
           var encodedScript = window.btoa(script);
           document.getElementById("submit-lnk").href = `/script-sent?authorize=${encodedScript}`;
           return false;
           };
    </script>
```

I know for sure that the `encodedScript` contains the correct value. The problem comes after that when I change the href. Even though its written syntactically correct, the page just reloads or nothing happens. I tested the templated string and it shows fine as well. Can someone please give me any guidance? Thank you!

Comment: The HTML is invalid, [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element can't contain interactive content.

Comment: I removed the button and left just the <a>. It was still the same problem

Comment: Are you still handling POST method on the server-side, though the link creates a GET request.

Comment: You need onsubmit of form, to prevent sending data to next page and do action when this happen.

Comment: Nothing happens because you `return false` from the link.  Remove that (assuming the button also removed as per comments above)

Comment: @jcubic I tried with your solution and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the anchor tag from within the button.

```
<button id = "what" class="submit-btn" type="submit">
   <!-- remove this -->
   <a id = "submit-lnk" class="submit-link" href = "#">Submit for Approval</a>
</button>
```

Instead of replacing the href you can simply redirect to the page directly

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("submit-lnk").onclick = function () {
        var script = document.getElementById("textarea-script-approval").value;
        var encodedScript = window.btoa(script);

        // instead of replacing the href you can simply redirect to the page directly
        window.location.href = `/script-sent?authorize=${encodedScript}`;

        return false;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the action on the form is blank. Try entering the path to the next page there.

Or use local storage to pass data in browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you need to do with jQuery

```
jQuery('#what').click(function(){
    jQuery('#script-approval-form').attr('action','insert link here');
    jQuery(this).click();
};
```

Comment: when you click the button the first time, theres no action so it wont do anything.
You then want to add an action, and click the button again.

Comment: Which will... call the same handler and add the action again and click the button *again*... which will... call the same handler and add the action again and click the button *again*... which will...